# Uniform convergence and bounded increasing function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have $0 \le f_n(x) \le 1$ and $f_n(x)$ is increasing on $\Bbb R$.
 I think I can say $f_n(x)$ converges.
Then I am not sure if it means $f_n(x)$ converges in a both way.
 I eventually need to show that there is a subsequence that converges in $Q$. What am I missing or thinking wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that each function $f_n$ is increasing as a function of $x$? or that for each fixed $x$, the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is increasing?

Comment: I am not given any more information. So that is maybe why I am confusing. I assume both though.

Comment: Take the functions $f_n(x) = |\sin n| x$. These are increasing functions which do not converge as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Why is yours increasing function? Isn't it oscillating?